# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') angular ssr

Tags: server-side-rendering

i have lazy load module pattern in my angular app , i can acces my route game module whe i use ng serve , but when i use npm run build:ssr and npm run serve:ssr i have some error like my title , can someone explaine me why i got error

**this is my route module**
[image: this is my route module]

**this is my game module**
[image]

**this is my game component**
[image]

**this is my game init component**
i use platform browser to handle ssr
[image]

**and i got error when run on ssr mode**
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem when I set `"optimation": true` in angular.json